# Box2d working on dynamically created bodies

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to learn box2d but i've a problem. I have 3 bodies in my project, 3 lines actually. i'm trying to set each lines y coordinate to -7 when they arrive to y coordinate 14. my code for checking if they are over 14 is below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < groundsArray.size(); i++) {

     Body body2 = groundsArray.get(i);

     float x_deg;
     x_deg = body2.getTransform().getPosition().x;

  if (body2.getUserData().equals("grounds" + i)   && body2.getTransform().getPosition().y > 14) {
     body2.setTransform(x_deg, -7, 0);

  }

}
```

How i create bodies :

```
 public void createGrounds(int i) {

  // for some random positions
  int rnd = random.nextInt(10);
  int constant = -20;
  int new_y = i * 7;

  int result_x1 = constant + rnd;
  int result_x2 = result_x1 + 16;

  BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
  FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();

  // GROUND LEFT
  // body definition
  bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
  bodyDef.position.set(0, 0);


  // ground shape
  ChainShape groundShape = new ChainShape();
  groundShape.createChain(new Vector2[] { new Vector2(result_x1, -new_y),new Vector2(result_x2, -new_y) });

  // fixture definition
  fixtureDef.shape = groundShape;
  fixtureDef.friction = 5f;
  fixtureDef.restitution = 0;

  grounds = world.createBody(bodyDef);
  grounds.createFixture(fixtureDef);

  grounds.setUserData("grounds" + i);
  groundsArray.add(grounds);

  groundShape.dispose();
}
```

How i call createGrounds() inside show():

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
     createGrounds(i);

  }
```

How i update the world and positions inside render():

```
  public void render(float delta) {
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  accelX = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
  Vector2 gravity = new Vector2(-accelX * 6, -60.81f);
  world.setGravity(gravity);

  world.step(TIMESTEP, VELOCITYITERATIONS, POSITIONITERATIONS);

  batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
  batch.begin();

  world.getBodies(tmpBodies);
  for (Body body : tmpBodies) {

     if (body.getUserData().equals(ballsprite)
           && body.getUserData() instanceof Sprite) {
        Sprite sprite = (Sprite) body.getUserData();
        sprite.setPosition(
              body.getPosition().x - sprite.getWidth() / 2,
              body.getPosition().y - sprite.getHeight() / 2);
        sprite.setRotation(body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
        sprite.draw(batch);
     }

     float x_deg;
     float y_deg;

     x_deg = body.getTransform().getPosition().x;
     y_deg = body.getTransform().getPosition().y;
     y_deg = y_deg + game_speed;
     body.setTransform(x_deg, y_deg, 0);

  }

  // The part i couldn't solve
  for (int i = 0; i < groundsArray.size(); i++) {

     Body body2 = groundsArray.get(i);

     float x_deg;
     x_deg = body2.getTransform().getPosition().x;

     if (body2.getUserData().equals("grounds" + i)
           && body2.getTransform().getPosition().y > 14) {
        body2.setTransform(x_deg, -7, 0);

     }

  }

  batch.end();
  debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
```

}

Comment: At a quick glance I dont see anything wrong. I would recommend that you test if all 3 bodies meet the conditions to do the "setTeansform". YOu can do that by writting to a log the values that interest you the most of your variable body2 inside the if.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your for cycle to this

```
for(int i = groundsArray.size(); i > 0; i--){}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i've tried this but get the same result. all of the lines acts like one body as before. i don't know but maybe i did sth wrong when creating or rendering. because of this i've edited my question with the render and create code.

Comment: I'm noob at box2d,sorry.